# How to convert a list of lists into a list of tuple + list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of lists, such as

```
l =  ["{{{1star}}} Do not bother with this  restaurant.",  "{{{1star}}}
The food is good but the service is awful."]
```

I would like to convert this list into a different list. The new list would contain a tuple and another list. The first element of the tuple would be what is inside `{{}}` as a string and the second element of the tuple would contain the rest of the text as a list. I am expecting the following output:

```
output =  [("{{{1star}}}", ["Do not bother with this  restaurant."]), 
("{{{1star}}}", ["The food is good but the service is awful."])]
```

Thank you!

Comment: please review your syntax it doesn't make sense, are those strings ?

Comment: Please edit your attempt to code this into your question. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to get what you want with some string manipulation

```
l =  ["{{{1star}}} Do not bother with this  restaurant.",  "{{{1star}}} The food is good but the service is awful."]

out = []

for strings in l : 
  s = strings.split()
  first = s[0] 
  second = strings.replace(s[0],'')
  tuple = ( first , second ) 
  out.append(tuple)

print(out)
```

or using regex

```
import re

l =  ["{{{1star}}} Do not bother with this  restaurant.",  "{{{1star}}} The food is good but the service is awful."]

out = []

for strings in l : 
  s = re.match( r'(.*)\}(.*?) .*', strings, re.M|re.I)
  print(s)
  if s : 
    first = s.group(1) + '}'
    second = strings.replace(first,'')
    tuple = ( first , second ) 
    out.append(tuple)

print(out)
```